# AudioFileID Read & Write

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I want to read from `AudioFileID` and then write to the end of it with this method (make it loop):

```
        UInt64 outDataSize = 0;
        UInt32 thePropSize = sizeof(UInt64);
        OSStatus result = AudioFileGetProperty(mBackupRecordFile, kAudioFilePropertyAudioDataByteCount, &thePropSize, &outDataSize);

        UInt32 readPoint  = outDataSize;
        void* theData = malloc(outDataSize);

        OSStatus result2 = AudioFileReadBytes(mBackupRecordFile, FALSE, 0, &readPoint, theData);

        UInt32 writeBytes = readPoint;

        OSStatus result3 = AudioFileWriteBytes(mBackupRecordFile, FALSE, readPoint, &writeBytes, theData);
```

The problem is that in result3 i get a big number and not 0 and the file won't increase.
the value of result3 is 1869627199 = kAudioFileOperationNotSupportedError

Comment: OMG, I have the same problem as you. Couldn't figure out what to do in this case.

Comment: I have posted a question on the developer forum.https://devforums.apple.com/thread/212641?tstart=0